# Does Amazon Alexa use Stack Exchange content, and if so, is it done legally?

Tags: discussion, legal, licensing, creative-commons, amazon

According to the Stack Exchange [content license](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) ([CC-BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)), uses of content on Stack Exchange sites must be [properly attributed](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).

However, I have noticed Amazon Alexa (accessed using an Echo device) return content that appears to be taken verbatim from Stack Exchange sites, with no attribution thereof. For example:

> Alexa, is there a car?
>
> There is no car. The first one is singular, the second one is plural. However, because there is a negation, the result is the same: there are zero cars.

[image: There is no car]

A web search reveals the response to be a fragment of [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/32844) from the English Language Learners Stack Exchange site.

Unfortunately, this particular query is not reproducible for me. But with some effort, I expect we could find other examples of such content usage.

My questions are:

- Is Alexa known to use Stack Exchange content?
- Is an attribution accomplished somehow?
- If not, should anything be done about it?

P.S. I found a [similar discussion about Echoes using content from Wikipedia](https://lists.gt.net/wiki/foundation/828732), but nothing about Stack Exchange.

Comment: Have you asked Alexa?

Comment: @Richard I tried asking lots of things like "What is the source of your content" and "What is your source" and "Where does your information come from" and "What is the license of your content" and "Do you use content from Wikipedia" and "Do you use content from Stack Exchange" but haven't hit upon any fruitful questions.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJRT6.png